# Choosing an appropriate complete orthogonal basis

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces, special-functions

I have a function $f(x)$ which I want to represent as the sum over some complete orthogonal basis $\phi_i$ such that:

$$ f(x) = \sum_{i} c_i \phi_i(x) $$

Where the $\phi_i$ are orthogonal with respect to some inner product:

$$ \langle \phi_i, \phi_j \rangle = 0, \quad i \ne j $$

I've done this without issue for a few different choices of basis (Chebyshevs, cosines) but given that I know $f(x)$ will have certain properties I'm wondering if there is a better choice, for example allowing me to truncate the series earlier without sacrificing accuracy.

$f(x)$ has the following properties:

- $f(x)$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$
- $f(x) \ge 0$ everywhere
- $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$
- $f(x)$ is real-valued everywhere

**Can anyone suggest some appropriate basis?**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does $f$ belong to a "special" functional space?

Comment: By orthogonal, do you mean $$\int_0^\infty \phi_k(x)\bar\phi_n(x)dx=0 ?$$

Comment: @AD. just that $\phi_n$ are orthogonal with respect to some unspecified inner product $\langle \phi_n, \phi_k \rangle = 0, n \ne k$. I'll edit the question to be more specific about this, thanks.

Comment: @CBowman Then it should possible to transform the problem to $(0,1)$, solve it there, and transform the result to $(0,+\infty)$.